# Understanding CDF and its relationship with Probability of r.v.

Tags: probability, random-variables

[image]

I attempted to solve this problem myself. I am trying to solve the problem by applying the fundamental formula of CDF. I.e. $P(X≤x) = F_X(x)$.

Let us see the problem *(b)*.

*(i)*  $P(X \le \frac{1}{4})$
$\Rightarrow F(\frac{1}{4})$  (*according to definition*)
$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2}$
$\Rightarrow \frac{3}{4}$

*(ii)* $P(0 < X \le \frac{1}{4})$
$\Rightarrow P(X \le \frac{1}{4}) - P(X \le 0)$  *(coz, it excludes $0$)*
$\Rightarrow F(\frac{1}{4}) - F(0)$    (*according to definition*)
$\Rightarrow \frac{3}{4} - \frac{1}{2}$
$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{4}$

*(iii)* $P(X=0)$
$\Rightarrow P(X \le 0) - P(?)$ ***(couldn't figure out! kindly, help.)***

*(iv)* $P(0 \le X \le \frac{1}{4})$
$\Rightarrow P(X \le \frac{1}{4}) - P(X \le 0) + P(0)$ ***(am I correct?)***

(i) and (ii) are okay. But, I am not sure about (iii), and (iv).

Also, (iii) uses a peculiar notation: $F(0^-)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you are asking since the answers are in the picture. Here is some reasoning behind iii) and iv).

iii) is given by $P(x\leq 0) - P(x<0)$ since we want the probability that $X=0$. Since $F(x)$ is defined to be $0$ for $x<0$ this gives $\frac{1}{2} - 0 = \frac{1}{2}$.

iv) We want the probability of $0\leq X\leq \frac{1}{4}$. If we take $F(\frac{1}{4}) - F(0)$ only then we leave out the probability that $X = \frac{1}{2}$ so this is added back in by the result in iii).

**Update:**

$F(0^-)$ simply means $P(X<0)$.

Your answer to *(iv)* is correct.

Comment: Remember that the cumulative distribution function gives the combined probability of everything to the left of x if you imagine the number line. Usually to find point probabilities using the cumulative distribution function you need to consider the difference between two cumulative probabilities. That is exactly what is done in iii), you start with the cumulative probability of $X$ being less than or equal to $0$ and subtract all the probability that $X$ is less than zero, leaving only the probability of $X$ being equal to zero.

Comment: "Not quite sure what you are asking ..." --- I am trying to solve the problem by applying the fundamental formula of CDF. I.e. $P(X \le x) = F_X(x)$. (i) and (ii) are okay. But, I am not sure about (iii), and (iv).

Comment: @user366312 In that case I believe it is solved as I tried to describe above. If anything is not clear then please ask specifically about what is not clear and I will try to give you an answer

Comment: (1) Can I not use the strange symbol $F(0^-)$ and still solve the problem? (2) How does your "iii" comply with the fundamental formula? (3) Was my attempted "iv" correct?

Comment: Yes, that symbol only means that you are subtracting all cumulative probability up to, but not including $x=0$. You can solve it the way I wrote it in my answer. iii) uses the fundamental formula since you first take $P(X\leq 0)$ which equals $F(0)$ by definition and then you subtract the totalt probability that $x<0$. $F(0^-)$ is the same as $P(X<0)$. Your iv) is correct as far as I can tell.

Comment: Kindly, update your main answer with what you have written in the comment so that I can accept it. Delete comments after update is done.

Comment: Edited, please accept. The comments may benefit others so I do not see the value in deleting them.